# Greenrobot's EventBus on a normal Java application

Tags: java, android, greenrobot-eventbus

I've been developing `Android` apps and I've been using `Greenrobot EventBus`, you can find it [here](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), and I really like it. Clean, versatile and easy to use.

Now I'm creating a Java Application and if I use an event bus it will help me a bit. So I thought about using `Greenrobot EventBus` but then it is made for `Android` and I'm not sure if there's any problem behind it while using it with a normal `Java Application`, after all they are both in `Java`.

I'm aware of other Event Bus libraries, like `Guava` and `Akka`, but since I'm already confortable with `Greenrobot EventBus` and it is very flexible with multi threading (which will help me as well) I'm thinking on using `Greenrobot` and save some time.

Comment: greenrobot's EventBus is based on Guava's EventBus. I will be rather surprised if greenrobot's EventBus works on plain Java projects.

Comment: @CommonsWare I didn't try it yet in a Java Application so I can't say it will work. I just thought I should ask first before diving into it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried to use this library (version *2.4.0*, last stable version) in a plain Java Project.
It seems that it is **not possible** to use it due to the *Android dependencies*.

```
import de.greenrobot.event.EventBus;

public class MainTest {
    EventBus eventBus = EventBus.getDefault();

    eventBus.post("This is a test event object");
}
```

A `ClassNotFoundException` is triggered:

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xttlP.png)

P.S.: I didn't try version *3.0.0-beta1*.